# Problem in Charachter Controller in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

[Problem Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hU8HP.png)
Hey guys, i have a problem in my Character controller in unity. I have a script joint with "Body" Component to rotate the object.  
The problem is in the character controller component and the capsule collider which is that when i am editing things, collider stays in the object but when i play the game, it seperates from the object due to the two colliders colliding as seen in the pic above and the object rotate on controller collider's axis.

If i remove the **capsule collider**, my object **falls** down and i need character controller to move my object..

Comment: While you show "body" are all the parts zero's on the children? Eg is your core capsule centrrrd on zero?

Answer (score 0):

you could try removing the player's collider and putting the controller collider inside the player, just make sure to get the sizes correct if you decide to do that.

Comment: i got the object not to fall by disabling the rigidbody, but without rigidbody how can i apply physics to the object??

Comment: No you had to disable the collider not the rigidbody

Comment: I did but if i remove the collider and not the rigid body, player will fall down and only the collider outline is seen on the surface , not the mesh itself. The mesh falls down.

Comment: I searched for online solutions and all of them says we have to use the character controller and rigid body seperately and it is recommended to use character controller in 3rd person player.